# Dynamic multiple where clause in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, where-clause, expression-trees

I have a request query using linq. The query has multiple where clause say return list of items matching name and city.
Below is the piece of code I used for multiple where clause, but it returns empty set of items.
wherefield contains list of field names like name;city
wherefieldValue contains list of field values like james;delhi

```
 var where = FilterLinq<T>.GetWherePredicate(wherefield, wherefieldvalue).Compile();
 items = items.Where(where).OrderByDescending(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(a, null)).Skip

 public class FilterLinq<T>
 {
    public static Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> GetWherePredicate(string whereFieldList, string whereFieldValues)
    {
        //the 'IN' parameter for expression ie T=> condition
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);

        //combine them with and 1=1 Like no expression
        Expression combined = null;
        if (whereFieldList != null)
        {
            string[] field = whereFieldList.Split(';');
            string[] fieldValue = whereFieldValues.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0; i < field.Count(); i++)
            {
                //Expression for accessing Fields name property
                Expression columnNameProperty = Expression.Property(pe, field[i]);

                //the name constant to match 
                Expression columnValue = Expression.Constant(fieldValue[i]);

                //the first expression: PatientantLastName = ?
                Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(columnNameProperty, columnValue);

                if (combined == null)
                {
                    combined = e1;
                }
                else
                {
                    combined = Expression.And(combined, e1);
                }
            }
        }

        //create and return the predicate
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(combined, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit more code than needed for my taste, but no obvious bugs as soon as fields are `string` type` (`Expression.And` should be `Expression.AndAlso`, but that shouldn't change the result). Can you post a sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The second line of your code seems to be incomplete. It may be a stupid question but are you sure that the where-clause filters out all elements? Is there a chance that, instead, the problem is related to the `Skip` statement at the end of the line?

Comment: Thanks all for the details. I have one whereField which is int and another a string. I wil try to convert int to string before and will check

Answer (score 0):

Your example works. Sure it works only for string properties, but i assume, that is your use case. 
Perhaps it doesn't do what you want to achieve, becasue you combine your clause with and, but actually you do want to do it with Or, jus change this code line :

```
combined = Expression.And(combined, e1);
```

To

```
combined = Expression.Or(combined, e1);
```